# How to ensure authors have a unique name

Tags: r, tidyverse

I extracted publication data from Microsoft Academic. Unfortunately, some authors have different versions of their names, e.g.

`names <- data.frame(publication_id  = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), author = c("D Smith", "D J Smith", "David Smith", "Enrique Salvador", "E J  Salvador"), affiliation = c("UCT", "UCT", "UCT", "UTAS", "UTAS")`

I want authors to have a unique name. Using the above example, I want to get a result that looks like this:

`names <- data.frame(publication_id  = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), author = c("D. Smith", "D Smith", "D Smith", "E Salvador", "E Salvador"), affiliation = c("UCT", "UCT", "UCT", "UTAS", "UTAS")`

I am dealing with 1000s of author names so using something like:

`mutate(author = case_when(author == "D.J. Smith" ~ "D. Smith", author == "David Smith" ~ "D.Smith",`

is impractical. I would appreciate any ideas/solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also get orcid numbers or researcher ids? If you manage to find a solution, every database on the world will want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most likely thing to work would be to take the first letter of the string and the last name and put them together:

```
names <- data.frame(publication_id  = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), author = c("D Smith", "D J Smith", "David Smith", "Enrique Salvador", "E J  Salvador"), affiliation = c("UCT", "UCT", "UCT", "UTAS", "UTAS"))
names$new_author <- paste0(substr(names$author, 1, 1), 
                           " ",  
                           gsub('.*\\s(\\w*)$', '\\1', names$author))
names
#    publication_id           author affiliation new_author
# 1              1          D Smith         UCT    D Smith
# 2              2        D J Smith         UCT    D Smith
# 3              3      David Smith         UCT    D Smith
# 4              4 Enrique Salvador        UTAS E Salvador
# 5              5    E J  Salvador        UTAS E Salvador
```

That said, it assumes that there is only one D Smith at UCT which may be an untenable assumption.

Comment: Your point about the assumption is valid. I have a field of study attribute that helps mitigate this issue. Dianne Smith and David Smith may be a married couple working together in the same field at the same institution. That would pose a challenge.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/01/string-manipulations-on-full-names/ is also quite helpful.